# sizeof operator in c on pointers of same type giving different results in C

Tags: c

I know that a pointer has a size similar to the device address architecture. But I am unable to get why same function and arguments are giving different results. Please look at the code and let me know what's the cause.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t a[22]={1,2,3,4,5};
    uint8_t* p[2]={a};
    printf("%d\n%d\n",&a,p[0]);
    printf("%d,%d",sizeof(a),sizeof(p));

    return 0;
}
```

606584768
606584768
22,16

Comment: Neither `a` nor `p` are pointers. They are arrays.

Comment: @EugeneSh. true but sizeof(p[0]) also returns 8.

Comment: @SaitejaPabisetti: `p[0]` is of pointer type.

Comment: Please don't change your question after answer have been posted. Rolled back.

Comment: Use `%p` to print pointer btw.

Comment: @JohnBode but the address we are sending to the function is the same. If an array deprecates to a pointer then both should be same. That's my concern

Comment: sizeof() is not a runtime function, (usually).  It is a compiler funny.

Comment: Array expressions *don't* decay when they're operands of `sizeof` (which is an operator, not a function).  That's one of the exceptions to the decay rule.

Comment: What does the signature of "the function" look like for the p parameter?  Does it take a uint8_t **p?  uint8_t *p[]?  uint8_t *p[2]?

Answer (score 3):

An array and pointer are not of the same type, an array will decay to a pointer but is not itself a pointer.

sizeof(a) gives the actual size of an uint_8[22], while sizeof(p) gives the actual size of an uint8_t *[2];

Comment: The point I didn't get is, both point to the same address. The thing is I am asking about sizeof(p[0])

Comment: @SaitejaPabisetti: `p[0]` is an expression of *pointer* type, not array type, so `sizeof p[0]` will *not* give the same result as `sizeof a`, even though the address value stored in `p[0]` is the same as the address of `a`.  The types of the *expressions* are different.

Answer (score 1):

An expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will "decay" to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" *except* when the expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators.

The *expression* `a` has type "22-element array of `uint8_t`", so `sizeof a` will give you the same result as `sizeof (uint8_t) * 22`.  The expression `p` has type "2-element array of *pointer to* `uint8_t` (`uint8_t *`)", so `sizeof p` is the same as `sizeof (uint8_t *) * 2`.

To summarize:

```
a           == some_address;
sizeof a    == 22 ( sizeof (uint8_t) should be 1)

p           == some address;
p[0]        == address of the first element of a
sizeof p    == 2 * sizeof (uint8_t *) (assuming pointer size is 8, this will be 16)
sizeof p[0] == sizeof (uint8_t *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a different between a and b firstly let examine a

```
uint8_t a[22]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

this line of code means a is array consists of 22 elements each element has 8 bits (one byte) so sizeof(a) is 22*1=22
secondly with respect to b

```
uint8_t* p[2]={a};
```

this line of code means b is array of pointers consists of 2 elements type of pointers which have the same size with respect to design architecture so  so sizeof(p) is (2 pointer * 8 )=16

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(a) give array size which is 22
but sizeof(b) give the size of array of pointer which consists of two pointers (2*8=16)